# Cannot get Android Build to work in Cordova -VS 2013 Community on 64bit Windows-7

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I installed Apache Cordova 4.0 on a Windows 32 bit machine and it all worked perfectly.
I cannot get it do do the same on another PC which is 64 bit (if that makes a difference).
I've checked the Path variables etc as in other questions on this topic and all seems ok.
I get the following Build Output when I try to build a HelloWorld project:

```
\Debug
1>  Creating a new cordova project with name "HelloCordova" and id "io.cordova.hellocordova" at location "C:\Users\Billy

\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\bld\Debug"
1>  Using stock cordova hello-world application.
1>  cordova library for "www" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
1>  Copying stock Cordova www assets into "C:\Users\Billy\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects

\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\bld\Debug\www"
1>  ------ Adding platform: android
1>  Creating android project...
1>  Running command: C:\Users\Billy\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\create.bat --cli "C:\Users

\Billy\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\bld\Debug\platforms\android" 

io.cordova.BlankCordovaApp7 BlankCordovaApp7
1>  
1>  C:\Users\Billy\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
1>                      throw e;
1>                            ^
1>MDAVSCLI : error : Failed to run "android". Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and that the "android" 

command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your PATH.
1>      at C:\Users\Billy\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:43:27
1>      at exithandler (child_process.js:644:7)
1>      at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:660:5)
1>      at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:95:17)
1>      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:808:12)
1>  Command finished with error code 8: C:\Users\Billy\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\create.bat 

--cli,C:\Users\Billy\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\bld\Debug\platforms

\android,io.cordova.BlankCordovaApp7,BlankCordovaApp7
1>MDAVSCLI : error : C:\Users\Billy\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\create.bat: Command failed 

with exit code 8
1>Done executing task "MdaVsCli" -- FAILED.
1>Done building target "PrepareForRippleRequirements" in project "BlankCordovaApp7.jsproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.97
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped =========
```

I've spent many hours trying to get this to work including multiple installs, re-boots etc and comparing the install with the one that works.
Any pointers to what may be amiss would be great. This is my first question on this incredibly useful resource so apologies if I've missed anything. Thanks.

Cordova is version: 0.3.110914.1

Answer (score 2):

I've finally fixed this.
Despite having correct path to the correct version of Java, multiple copies of Java jre and SDK seemed to be causing the problem.
Variable: JAVA_HOME. Value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71
Path: ...;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;...
This is what I did (although all steps below may not be required):

1. Edit registry with regedit to point to correct versions (1.7) for JDK and JRE. (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JAVASOFT...)
2. Ensure jre7 and JDK1.7.0_71 were in the same folder. In my case
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71 and C:\Program Files\Java\jre7.
3. In Control Panel uninstall all versions of Java jre and SDK except
   the two listed above in that location. (I had multiple copies of 1.7 and 1.8 in various places).
4. Re-boot.